# How to choose the port by node soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, wsdl, node-soap

if the wsdl have two port, how can i choose the name http? Used the node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

```
 <wsdl:service name="ws">
    <wsdl:port name="http" binding="calcB">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/wscalc1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="https" binding="calcB">
      <soap:address location="https://localhost:8000/wscalc1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the binding associated with your operation. The port with the same binding will be used.